# SQL - group by one column but select multiple columns from different rows as colums

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have table which looks like this:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | AcID | TypeID | Value1 | Value2 | Notes |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1  | 33   | 1      | Hash1  | Dash1  |       |
| 2  | 33   | 2      | Hash2  | Dash2  |       |
| 3  | 33   | 3      | Hash3  | Dash3  |       |
| 4  | 33   | 4      | Hash4  | Dash4  | lala  |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

After select I would like to have result which looks like :

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+
| AcID | TypeID1 | TypeID2 | TypeID3 | TypeID4 | TypeID4_Notes |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+
| 33   | Hash1   | Hash2   | Hash3   | Dash4   |     lala      |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+
```

with Pivot i can get:

```
SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(value1)
FOR typeID IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable
```

Result :

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| hash1 | Hash2 | Hash3 | Hash4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How could I add actID to result + change type4 value to Dash4 and add column called Notes wich contains value of type4 notes. Header names dont matter just need to get needed data fields into result.

Thanks

Solution:
Got it work end query ->

```
SELECT * FROM   (SELECT AcID,
               CASE
                 WHEN cname = 'Notes' THEN 'typeID' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), typeID) + '_' + cname
                 ELSE cname + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), typeID)
               END AS typeid,
               data
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       AcID,
                       typeID,
                       CASE
                         WHEN typeID <> 4 THEN Value1
                         ELSE Value2
                       END AS typeids,
                       Notes
                FROM   mytable) a
               CROSS apply (VALUES ('typeid',CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),typeids)),
                                   ('Notes',notes)) cs(cname, data)) b
       PIVOT (Max(data)
             FOR typeid IN ([typeid1],[typeid2],[typeid3],[typeid4],
                            [typeid4_Notes] )) pv
```

Now there is one more question -> why do i have to convert typeids to string value ? (originaly in db they are datetimes, but it throws me error when i wont convert) @NoDisplayName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to pivot two column `value` and `notes` I will suggest you to first convert both the columns into single column using `cross apply`

Then pivot the column to get the result.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT AcID,
               CASE
                 WHEN cname = 'notes' THEN 'typeid' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), id) + '_' + cname
                 ELSE cname + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), id)
               END AS typeid,
               data
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       AcID,
                       CASE
                         WHEN notes <> '' THEN Value1
                         ELSE Value2
                       END AS typeids,
                       Notes
                FROM   Yourtable) a
               CROSS apply (VALUES ('typeid',typeids),
                                   ('Notes',notes)) cs(cname, data)) b
       PIVOT (Max(data)
             FOR typeid IN ([typeid1],[typeid2],[typeid3],[typeid4],
                            [typeid4_Notes] )) pv
```

Comment: I want to pivot 3 columns value1, value2, notes. Value2 will be selected from row with typeid 4 into TypeiD4 column nevertheless notes are emty or not. But i got some ideas, trying to use them will let you know how it went.